# Deleting row using PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to delete from table.2 if no row count exist or < than one in table.1. using a variable ($group). I think the problem is after I delete the row in table.1 there’s no variable to go by to delete in table.2 so it doesn not delete the row. I don’t know if this makes sense. Here’s the code.

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT `group name` FROM `group` WHERE cid = '$id'") or die(mysql_error());
list($group) = mysql_fetch_row($q);

$n = mysql_query("select count(`group name`) as total from `group` WHERE user_id
= '$_SESSION[user_id]' AND cid = '$id' ");

$r = mysql_fetch_array($n);

if($r['total'] = 0 ) {

mysql_query("DELETE FROM `group log`
             WHERE `group name`='$group'
            ") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

I’ve also tried this but it just deletes the row after user deletes all rows:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `group log` 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                    FROM `group` g
                   WHERE g.`group name` = `group name`)");
```

Comment: Can you show the `show create table yourtable` output? You cannot have spaces in MySQL column names...

Comment: `if($r['total'] = 0 )` should have `==`

Comment: @Marcell Fülöp CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `group` (
`id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `photo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `group log` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `created` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just looking to delete records of one table that don't have a corresponding match in a second table, the `DELETE` method in MySQL supports `LEFT JOIN` syntax:

```
DELETE gl.* 
FROM `group log` gl
LEFT JOIN `group` g
ON g.`group name` = gl.`group name`
WHERE g.`group name` IS NULL
```

Or, if you have a particular group you're looking to delete from the log table:

```
DELETE gl.* 
FROM `group log` gl
LEFT JOIN `group` g
ON g.`group name` = gl.`group name`
WHERE g.`group name` IS NULL
AND gl.`group name` = '$group'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
`WHERE g.`group name` = `group name`)
```

Thats saying

```
where `group name` = `group name`
```

Which is always true, I suspect you meant to say

```
where `group name` = 'group name'
```

or

```
where `group name` = $group_name
```

in the first case you missed a `=` it should be

```
if($r['total'] == 0 ) {
```

Comment: But if there is no variable to go off of, it nulls the statement and there's nothing in variable $group_name. Would sessions be best, and how would I would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answer by exussum, I would exchange

```
$n = mysql_query("select count(`group name`) as total from `group` WHERE user_id='$_SESSION[user_id]' AND cid = '$id' ");
```

with

```
$n = mysql_query("select count(`group name`) as total from `group` WHERE user_id= '{$_SESSION['user_id']}' AND cid = '$id' ");
```

To avoid an undefined constant error notice, depending on the error settings used:

**$_SESSION[user_id]** is actually looking for the value of the constant **user_id** to use as the key in **$_SESSION**, but defaults to the string 'user_id' (albeit with a warning).

Also, have you checked that the session is started (**session_start()**) and that **$_SESSION['user_id']** is set?

Comment: session_start(); is already set at the top of the script. There's no errors. The issue is with variable $group if the count(`group name`) is == 0 (NULL). $group does not have any data string. i.e. where `group name` = $group

Comment: And the row with  cid = '$id' exists for $id I guess..?

Comment: $cid is it's own variable. Nothing to do with $_SESSION[user_id]